# Delphi OpenSSL Encryption/Decryption

Tags: delphi, openssl, base64, sha1

i would like to achieve the command from Delphi to pass String parameter and get a string result , and the encryption result should be able to be decrypted in another application with public key ,any one can help ?

```
   1) openssl dgst -sha1 -sign PrivateKey.pem -out OutSHA.sha1 Imput.txt
   2) openssl enc -base64 -in  OutSHA.sha1 -out OutB64.b64 -A 




PrivateKey.pem= Private key 
Imput.txt = clear text to encrypt 
OutSHA.sha1 = result from 1 command 
OutB64.b64= final result (text)
```

Use Chilkat component , but i can't decrypt it in the other application

```
function Tf_invsign.EncSHAB64(s: string): String;
var
  pkey: HCkPrivateKey;
  success:Boolean;
  rsa:HCkRsa;
  b64Sig:PWideChar;
begin
    addlog(s);
    pkey := CkPrivateKey_Create();
    success := CkPrivateKey_LoadEncryptedPemFile(pkey,'private.PEM','');
    if not success then begin
      addlog(CkPrivateKey__lastErrorText(pkey));
      Exit;
    end;
    rsa := CkRsa_Create();
    success := CkRsa_ImportPrivateKeyObj(rsa,pkey);
    if not success then begin
      addlog(CkRsa__lastErrorText(rsa));
      Exit;
    end;
   CkRsa_putLittleEndian(rsa,True);
   CkRsa_putEncodingMode(rsa,'base64');
   {S is String and Var wideChar for that i'm use Addr() will return the first 
    addressing string, mean the string}
   b64Sig := CkRsa__signStringENC(rsa,Addr(s[1]),'sha1'); 
   if not success then begin
     addlog(CkRsa__lastErrorText(rsa));
     Exit;
   end;
   Result:=b64Sig;
   kPrivateKey_Dispose(pkey);
   CkRsa_Dispose(rsa);
end;
```

Comment: What have you achieved so far and where do you fail? StackOverflow is for asking questions, not delegating work.

Comment: You haven't read or understood https://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/dd_CkRsaRef.html#method37 because `'sha1'` is no expected value - have you even checked what `b64Sig` contains? Which "other application"?

Comment: Sure, checked and i believe i fount the issue , thank you

Comment: @YuriAdam What was the issue?

Comment: Sorry for the Delay , I resolved with another solution , code written in Delphi and available for other platform and the [link](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/portugal_DGCI_billing_software.html#delphicode)